# Load two copies of a model in TensorFlow

Tags: variables, scope, tensorflow

I have trained an LSTM model in TensowFlow and have saved it using the tf.train.Saver class as per the [instructions on saving and loading variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/how_tos/variables/index.html#saving-and-restoring). I now want to load two copies of this model and create a larger RNN which combines them, for further training. Unfortunately, as far as I can see there is no way to load variables from one scope into another. Is there any way to do this?

As a simple example, suppose I had a simple model:

```py
with tf.variable_scope("model", reuse=None, initializer=initializer):
      W = tf.get_variable("W", [input_size, output_size])
      b = tf.get_variable("b", [input_size])

      inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, input_size]      
      outputs = tf.matmul(inputs, W) + b
```

And I trained this model on some data and saved the variables using:

```py
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saved.save(session, "model")
```

Then later I wanted to create a combined model:

```py
with tf.variable_scope("combinedl", reuse=None, initializer=initializer):
    with tf.variable_scope("model0" , reuse=None, initializer=initializer):
         W0 = tf.get_variable("W", [input_size, output_size])
         b0 = tf.get_variable("b", [input_size])

         inputs0 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, input_size]      
         outputs0 = tf.matmul(inputs, W0) + b0

    with tf.variable_scope("model1" , reuse=None, initializer=initializer):
         W1 = tf.get_variable("W", [input_size, output_size])
         b1 = tf.get_variable("b", [input_size])

         inputs1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, input_size]      
         outputs1 = tf.matmul(inputs, W1) + b1

    output = outputs1 + outputs2
```

Would it be possible to load the trained values for W and b in the original model into the variables W0, b0 and W1, b1? Would it be possible to train these new variables independently?

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer, it seems, would be to reload the original model and then assign the values of W0, b0, W1, b1 to the original W and b.

```
with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(W0.assign(W))
    session.run(b0.assign(b))
    session.run(W1.assign(W))
    session.run(b1.assign(b))
```

However this requires looking inside the model and knowing all the relevant variables that need to be copied.

Edit: A hacky way to copy all the variables without knowing the internal details of the model, assuming they have the same names:

```
with tf.variable_scope("old_model", reuse=None, initializer=initializer) as scope:
    old_model = Model()
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.restore(session, "saved_model")

    # create a dictionary of variables in this scope indexed by name
    old_vars = {v.name.split('/')[-1] : v 
                for v in tf.trainable_variables() 
                if v.name.startswith(scope.name + "/")}

with tf.variable_scope("new_model", reuse=None, initializer=initializer) as scope:
    new_model = Model()
    assignments = [vNew.assign(old_vars[vNew.name.split('/')]) 
                   for v in tf.trainable_variables() 
                   if v.name.startswith(scope.name + "/")]
```